# Hybris remove specific cookie when logout

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I've created a custom cookie via Javascript and every time I logout, I want to remove this cookie from the browser. How/Where is the best place to  perform this operation in the Hybris/Sap Commerce ecosystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring MVC Interceptors like this.

```
<alias name="defaultBeforeControllerHandlersList" alias="beforeControllerHandlersList"/>
<util:list id="defaultBeforeControllerHandlersList">
    <!-- List of handlers to run -->
    <bean class="xyz.CheckUrlsBeforeControllerHandler">
        <property name="checkedUrls" ref="checkUrlsList"/>
    </bean>
   
  
</util:list>
```

Then Inside CustomHandler use guidCookieStrategy.deleteCookie(request, response);
to delete cookies.